# how to add UIWebview inside a view by coding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, uiview

In my app I dragged a View from the library of the interface builder and linked it to the AppDelegate.

my question is "can I add UIWebView inside the View ?"

and if make a special class (UIView class) for the view which method behaves like viewDidload ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can add a UIWebView inside the View.

```
[UIWebView *aWebView =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)]; aWebView.delegate=self; 
[self.view addSubview:aWebView]; 
[aWebView release];
```

In the above code you set the delegate of the WebView as self. So you can use the delegate methods of UIWebView like

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Refer this link for more details.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can simply use -

In your h file add

```
    @interface YourView:UIView<UIWebViewDelegate>{
```

in your m file add

```
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,200);
    UIWebView *webView =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame)];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [self addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: it is for view an not for UIView Controller. can you post the code you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   CGRect  rect=CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)  ;
   UIWebView *webView1 =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect)];
   webView1.delegate=self;
   [self.view addSubview:webView1];
   [webView1 release];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you view's outlet is named myView:

.h file

```
@interface myViewController:UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIView *myView;
}
```

.m file

```
UIWebView *,myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,myView.frame.size.width,myView.frame.size.height)];
myWebView.delegate = self;
[myView addSubView:myWebView];
```

It's not necissary to create another subclass to listen for deleagte methods of your view, i would now treat your UIView as a UIWebView and thus use UIWebView's delegate methods, like so:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  NSLog(@"started loading");
}
```

more delegate methods can be [found here in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). You could also use [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to listen for your own events application wide if you wish to fire something in a different class when the UIWebView is loaded.